# Texas Hold'em classes

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, playing-cards

I am working on a simple Texas Hold'Em dealing simulator. I am new to Python and was hoping to get some advice on my use of classes here. I feel like I am not using them as efficiently as possible, especially when dealing out the player cards. Specifically, I feel like the `def deal(self, n_players)` could be simplified instead of using `playercard1` and `playercard2`, and deleting the items from the "deck".

```
from random import shuffle

class TexasHoldem:
    #create deck
    def __init__(self):
        values = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
        suites = ['Heart', 'Spade', 'Club', 'Diamond']
        self.deck = [j + " " + i for j in values for i in suites]

    #shuffle deck
    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.deck)

    #deal for players
    def deal(self, n_players):
        count = 0
        #card 1 list (will be shuffled, delt 'around the table' as if a real stack)
        playercard1 = list()
        while count < n_players:
            card1 = self.deck[count]
            playercard1.append(card1)
            count += 1

        #remove cards from deck that were delt 
        for i in playercard1:
            self.deck.remove(i)

         count = 0
         #card 2 list 
         playercard2 = list() 
         while count < n_players:
             card2 = self.deck[count]
             playercard2.append(card2)
             count += 1

         #remove cards from deck delt for 2nd card
         for i in playercard2:
             self.deck.remove(i)

        #merge cards of playercard1 and playercard2 into set     
        self.playerhand = zip(playercard1, playercard2)

    #define the flop    
    def flop(self):
        #burn a card
        del self.deck[0]
        #lay down three
        self.flopcards = self.deck[0:3]
        #delete flop from deck
        for i in self.flopcards:
            self.deck.remove(i)

    #same as flop for turn and river        
    def turn(self):
        del self.deck[0]
        self.turncard = self.deck[0:1]

        for i in self.turncard:   
            self.deck.remove(i)

    def river(self):
        del self.deck[0]
        self.rivercard = self.deck[0:1]

        for i in self.rivercard:
            self.deck.remove(i)

#create instance of Cards class            
c = TexasHoldem()
#shuffle for this instance
c.shuffle()

#deal for n players
c.deal(9)

print 'Player Hands:'
for i in c.playerhand:
    print i

#flop
c.flop()
print 'Flop:'
print c.flopcards

#turn
c.turn()
print 'Turn:'
print c.turncard

#river
print 'River:'
c.river()
print c.rivercard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does a few things repetitively:

```
count = 0
playercard1 = list()
while count < n_players:
    card1 = self.deck[count]
    playercard1.append(card1)
    count += 1

for i in playercard1:
    self.deck.remove(i)
```

I'll go through the problems with this:

- You manually increment `count`, this is something that you should do with `range`.
- You manually index every item.
- You manually append to a list.
- You manually `remove` each card from the deck, this causes the list to shift, and causes a small search of the list. (\$O(n)\$ complexity)

Instead you could either:

1. Pop the amount of cards you need.

   ```
   pop = self.deck.pop
   playercard1 = [pop() for _ in range(n_players)]
   ```
2. Slice the amount of items you need and then delete them.

   ```
   playercard1 = self.deck[-n_players:]
   del self.deck[-n_players:]
   ```

You should notice that I take from the end of the list, this is as you aren't using a queue and so they will be faster.

---

The other main code you use is:

```
del self.deck[0]
self.flopcards = self.deck[0:3]
del self.deck[0:3]
```

This uses the same code as before, but burns one card.
You can then just make two functions to do what most of your code is doing at the moment.

```
def take(self, number_cards):
    pop = self.deck.pop
    return [pop() for _ in range(number_cards)]

def draw(self, number_cards):
    self.deck.pop()
    return self.take(number_cards)
```

This then makes the rest of your code simple and easy to read and use.

```
def deal(self, n_players):
    self.playerhand = zip(self.take(n_players), self.take(n_players))

def flop(self):
    self.flopcards = self.draw(3)

def turn(self):
    self.turncard = self.draw(1)

def river(self):
    self.rivercard = self.draw(1)
```

---

Other than the above I'd:

- Add `shuffle` to your `__init__` so that the cards are pre-shuffled.
- Move the deck creation into `shuffle` to allow more than one game, and
- Move values and suites to the global scope as 'constants'.

This results in something like:

```
VALUES = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
SUITES = ['Heart', 'Spade', 'Club', 'Diamond']
class TexasHoldem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shuffle()

    def shuffle(self):
        self.deck = [j + " " + i for j in VALUES for i in SUITES]
        shuffle(self.deck)
```